# Evans proof of the maximum principle for subharmonic functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian, maximum-principle

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded and open and $u:\overline\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be continuous. Suppose $M\in\mathbb R$ with $$M>u(x)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\Omega\tag1$$ and $x_0\in\partial\Omega$ with $$u(x_0)=M.$$

> Is it possible that there is a $\tilde x_0\in\partial\Omega$ with $u(\tilde x_0)>M$?

*Remark*: This question arose as I was reading [Evans proof othe maximum principle](https://books.google.com/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&pg=PA350&lpg=PA350&dq=%22In+view+of+(14)+there+exists+a+constant%22&source=bl&ots=dmchqFRqjP&sig=ACfU3U0nrMgKUEifIX10idg3SRJxcCZaiw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZxfL_n8nxAhUFC-wKHRHQAy8Q6AEwAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%22In%20view%20of%20(14)%20there%20exists%20a%20constant%22&f=false), where $\Omega=B_r(0)$ for some $r>0$. Instead of equation (17) therein, it is only clear to me that $\max_{\partial B_r(0)}u\ge u(x)+\varepsilon v(x)$ for all $x\in\partial B_r(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u$ is continuous in $\overline \Omega$ with $u(z) < M$ for all $z \in \Omega$ then $u(z) \le M$ for all $z \in \overline \Omega$.

It is therefore not possible that $u(\tilde x_0)>M$ for some $\tilde x_0\in\partial\Omega$.

Comment: Well, okay, the reason is simply continuity, right? If $\tilde x_0\in\partial\Omega$, then $x_n\to\tilde x_0$ for some $x_n\in\Omega$; hence $\tilde x_0\le\sup_nx_n\le M$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Yes, $u(\tilde x_0) = \lim u(x_n) \le M$ because of the continuity.